# Why is a string literal being over written here (C++)?

Tags: c++

I have a class holding a pointer.
I have only included skeleton code here. 
The class constructor expects a string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class slice {
public:
slice(string s):
    data_(s.data()),
    size_(s.size()) {}

    const string toString() {
        string res(data_, data_+size_);
        return res;
    }

private:
    const char* data_;
    const size_t size_;
};

int main() {

    slice a{"foo"};
    slice b{"bar"};


    cout << a.toString() << endl;
    cout << b.toString() << endl;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
$ g++ test.cpp && ./a.out 
bar
bar
```

I am expecting

```
foo
bar
```

What is going on here? How is the pointer held by object a being overwritten?

Comment: There is [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) since C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::string` objects calls its destructor `std::~string()` when it goes out of scope.

```
slice(string s) : data_(s.data()), size_(s.size()) {
    // After this function is called, the string goes out of scope and s.data() is deallocated by the destructor.
    // Leaving gibberish value inside of 'data_' member
}
```

Afterwards, when you actually print the value, `data_` was already destroyed by then and what you do with it afterwards results in *Undefined Behavior* (It means the behavior of the program when outputting the string can be anything, thus the term **undefined**).

---

Since this question has already been answered. I might as well give a reasonable solution.

**Solution:** Create a copy of what the string is holding temporarily inside your class and destroy it when your class goes out of scope:

*Example:*

```
class slice {
public:
    slice(string s):
        size_(s.size()) {
        // Dynamically allocate a new string so that it doesn't get deleted when it goes out of scope
        data_ = new char[s.size()];
        // Copy the data into the newly allocated string
        s.copy(data_, s.size());
    }

    slice(const slice&) = default; // Copy constructor
    slice(slice&&) = default;      // Move constructor

    // Destructor
    ~slice() {
        delete[] data_;
    }

    const string toString() {
        // Now 'data_' retains its value even after the string is destroyed
        string res(data_, data_+size_);
        return res;
    }

private:
    char* data_;
    const size_t size_;
};
```

Comment: That's an unnecessary `virtual` destructor, and you missed the Rule of Three (copy ctor and assignment are both broken) or the Rule of Zero (just have a `std::string member` so this is all unnecessary)

Comment: `data_` leaks after `slice` is destroyed in your implementation.

Answer (score 5):

> What is going on here? How is the pointer held by object a being overwritten?

You are experiencing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
slice(string s):
    data_(s.data()),
    size_(s.size()) {}
```

Here `string s` is a copy of the input string and lives for the duration of the constructor. Hence `s.data()` dangles after the constructor is finished.

Comment: That explanation makes sense. However, if my constructor is " slice(const string& s) " , why does the string literal still go out of scope? I would have expected it to be in scope until the end of main function.

Comment: That's because a temporary `std::string` is constructed from a string literal `"foo"`, and a reference is bound to that temporary. The temporary in that case lives until the end of the full-expression, usually the first `;`.

Answer (score 0):

a and b are being created from temporary string objects. When those string objects are destroyed by the end of the statement, they deallocate their memory, and the underlying char* pointing to where the characters were becomes invalid. You can't usually use a char* taken from a string like this.